# stopping criteria for power-iteration to find rank-1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I start with B=I, A positive matrix, and compute B=(BA)/norm(B) by iterating until B is sufficiently close to rank-1 matrix. What is a good stopping criterion for this algorithm?

There's Birkhoff contraction coefficient which measures how far matrix is from rank-1 matrix, but it's expensive, I'm looking for some GPU-friendly criterion I could apply to the difference B-B_old

Comment: What kind of matrix is $A$?  Is it a Markov (row-stochastic) matrix?  Is it doubly stochastic?  Can we assume that $A$ is ergodic (aperiodic and irreducible)?

Comment: A is a general positive matrix (all entries are positive). From Perron-Frobenius theorem it follows that A^k converges to rank-1 matrix

Comment: $A^k$ itself will only converge to a rank one matrix if the maximal eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$. Otherwise, it will converge to $0$ or diverge to $\infty$.

Comment: "converge to rank-1 matrix" could be made precise by a proper definition of convergence (ie, take a sequence of rank-1 matrices that only differ by a constant factor, and showing that sequence of A^k's converges to that sequence)

Comment: Although good point, going to infinity is no good, this can be fixed by dividing by norm(B) at each iteration, updated q

Comment: Okay, that's a little bit more standard. Seems to me like you should be able to just set a threshold for norm(B-B_old)/norm(B) and get a reasonable answer